# htaccess, apply rules just for some directory

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have a .htaccess file in base directory and there i have some folders

folder1 folder2 folder3

is there a way in base directory .htaccess to add some rules that will be just for 
folder1 folder2 folder3

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule \.m3u8 file.m3u8 [NC,L]


 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(vlc|LibVLC|Android|iPhone).*$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com [L,R=301]
```

so i want those rules to be just for those 3 folders, and not for base folder and other folders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(folder1|folder2|folder3)/` to target certain directories:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(folder1|folder2|folder3)/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule \.m3u8 file.m3u8 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(folder1|folder2|folder3)/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(vlc|LibVLC|Android|iPhone).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com [L,R=301]
```